# Hydrogen - No kernel for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, atom-editor, hydrogen

I have just installed Atom (latest version), then Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda, and finally Hydrogen.

[cmd.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsxa7.png)

" 'python' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes. "

> roughly translatable to :
>   " 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable file or a command file. "

I figured from various cources that this is a problem with the PATH variable, I'm still attempting to solve this.

Alright... well, too bad, let's try something else for now :

[Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaR8a.png)

Am I right to assume that this was fully successful ? I'm guessing that since it says "requirement already satisfied" it was not this particular execution that made it work, but I didn't do anything in-between...

Somehow now Hydrogen "decided" to work (I know it didn't do anything on its own, but I definitely did not solve this consciously), and I can finally do this : [In-editor execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW63f.png)

At that point, do I need other kernels for Python, or is everything I need already included in iPyKernel ? If not, what is the minimal list of kernels so that any situation can be handled ?

For the record :

- I only have Python 3.6.3 (no Python 2)
- I am under Windows 10

Thanks for reading, I hope you can help me.

Comment: the two commands in the "no kernel for grammar `Python` found" message should be run in a windows command prompt (`cmd.exe` or Windows Console). What "didn't work" when you ran those commands in the Windows command prompt? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51159578/edit) the question and post Traceback errors or more information about how it didn't work. Those commands are how you install python modules and jupyter kernels.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262